# Click sub-element button when it appears after clicking another button with Python Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, click, inspect

I'm having trouble with the Selenium webdriver's `click()` feature in Python when I'm trying to click on buttons that only appear after you click on a parent button.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

url = "https://law.lexmachina.com/cases/?pending-from=2000-01-01&pending-to=2000-02-01&filters=true&tab=summary&view=analytics&cols=475"
driver.get(url)
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
elem0 = driver.find_element_by_id('export-icon-container') # this works

all_children_by_css = elem0.find_elements_by_css_selector("*") # this works, but doesn't click on the sub-button (XLS) one successfully when I run below... 
all_children_by_css[0].click() # this just makes the parent button's little window appear and disappear, the same as elem0.click() does.

>>> all_children_by_css[0] # this is the webElement that I thought was for the XLS button
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="6b4a559408fa4d512f8596759d81eaf7", 
element="d83be2ca-c879-4706-85ef-db7120d345a3")>
```

Basically, I want to export the `XLS` file via the Webdriver, so that later on I can do this on a loop with URLs of filters of the data.

I included annotated screenshots below, detailing the buttons I'm trying to click & the inspected code associated with them.

[image: Inspected code for the parent button of interest]

[image: Inspected code for the parent button of interest when hovering over it]

[image: Inspected code for the parent button of interest when clicking on it]

[image: Inspected code for the newly-appeared button of interest (the XLS one). I can't get the Webdriver to click it.]

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to see if there an API on the page to export directly. if not, You would probably need dynamic wait. you can try something like below.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "https://law.lexmachina.com/cases/?pending-from=2000-01-01&pending-to=2000-02-01&filters=true&tab=summary&view=analytics&cols=475"
driver.get(url)

#Click on Export Icon
elem0 = driver.find_element_by_id('export-icon-container').click() 

#Wait for XLS option to show up
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
ExportOption= wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@data-action='export-item'][contains(text(),'XLS')]")))
ExportOption.click()
```

Comment: Sadly, the site purposefully lets you export only 1000 records at a time. The goal is to get the batches of the records on a loop. I tried your solution, but got this error: `>>> ExportOption= wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@data-action='export-item'][contains(text(),'XLS')]")))`... 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File ".../lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:`

Comment: Did the first click successful & XLS option showed up on the screen?

Comment: Yup, I've been able to do that. The little `XLS`, `PDF` Export window shows up when I do `driver.find_element_by_id('export-icon-container')` and when I do `elem0.find_elements_by_css_selector("*").click()` (the all_children_by_css object I have in my original question). The little window closes when I repeat the same call, as if those functions are toggling the window back and forth. But when I do the latter (the children click call), the former (elem0 click call) no longer opens & closes that little window anymore.